# Questions regarding an upconverter topology (biasing network and small overdrive problems)

Tags: rf, analog, mixer

This following diagram is taken from the textbook “RF Microelectronics” by Prof. Razavi.

[image]

I have a number of questions regarding this upconverter topology.

Q1
How can we tell from this upconverter (or any other mixer topology) whether the output is a double-side band signal or a single-side band signal?

Q2
It is mentioned that the gate of M5-M8 should be biased at 0.6V. However there is no biasing network connected to the gate of M5-M8. So why can we make sure the common mode voltage at M5-M8 is 0.6V?

Q3
If the M5 gate has to be biased at 0.6V and the gate of M1 is fed by an LO with a 1.2V swing, then why M1 will suffer from a small overdrive?

Q4
How the small overdrive of the M1-M4 degrades the performance of the upconverter?

Q5
Can increasing the width of M1-M4 help to solve the small overdrive problem?

Thanks.

Comment: HI! Can you split that? It's easy to answer Q1, in this case, for example, but hard to answer the others. So I won't write an answer. Generally, try to avoid asking very different questions within one question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for your reply. And sorry that I haven't made my questions clear. I just think all are related problems, so I asked them in a sequence. But if you know the answer of Q1, could you please advise only Q1? Thanks.

Comment: but then you couldn't accept the answer because it doesn't involved Q2-Q5?!